# How to calculate the integral homology of a cell complex?

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following 2-dimensional hexagon, with its edges oriented as
indicated by the arrows.
[image]

Let $X$ be the cell complex obtained by making the following three identifications on the edges of the hexagon: $a_1 = a_2, b_1 = b_2, c_1 = c_2$.

I am new in algebraic topology, so I am having trouble in understanding the construction of cell complexes. I have to find integral homology of $X$. Any help regarding this will be appreciated

Comment: 1) Compute the number of 0,1 and 2-cells. 2) Compute the maps of the  complex $\Bbb Z^a \to \Bbb Z^b \to \Bbb Z^c$. 3) Compute the homology, of the complex.

Comment: For getting started, can you prove that $H_2(X, \Bbb Z) = 0$ ?

Comment: No sir, can you provide me with some hints?

Comment: How many 2-cells your complex has ? What is the definition of the boundary map for these 2-cells ?

Comment: Please do not deface your post. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be your space, and let $B$ be a ball in the interior of your hexagon, and hence in your space. Choose $b\in B$, and the pair of open sets $(B,X\smallsetminus b)$ that intersect at $B\smallsetminus b$. Note that $X\smallsetminus b$ deformation retracts onto *three circles, one for each pair of edges in your hexagon.* Both the open sets and their intersection have trivial $H_i$ for $i>1$, and the  Mayer-Vietoris gives you that $H_i(X) = 0$ for $i>2$ and an exact sequence

$$0\to H_2(X) \to   H_1(B\smallsetminus b)\to H_1(X\smallsetminus b)\to H_1(X) \to \widetilde{H}_0(B\smallsetminus b)=0$$

The image of the map $H_1(X\smallsetminus b)\to H_1(X)$ is zero since the generators of $H_1(X\smallsetminus b)$ can be taken to be a loop traversing an edge once and going around $b$, which is nullhomologous in $X$. This means that we have a short exact sequence

$$0\to H_2(X) \to   H_1(B\smallsetminus b)\to H_1(X\smallsetminus b)\to 0$$

The last terms is $\mathbb Z^3$, and you can check that the arrow $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z^3$ is given by $(2,2,2)^t$ under the identification above. This means that $H_2(X) = 0$, since this map is injective.

Since the kernel of $H_1(X) \to 0$ is the cokernel of $(2,2,2)^t$, we get that $H_1(X)= \mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$, and of course $X$ is connected. To see this last claim, you may compute the Smith normal form of the
corresponding matrix, or note that there is an automorphism of $\mathbb Z^3$ that sends $e_1\to e_1+e_2+e_3$, $e_2\to e_2$ and $e_3\to e_3$, and the subgroup
generated by $(2,0,0)$ to that generated by $(2,2,2)$.

Comment: The surface seems to be $\Bbb{RP}^2 \#\Bbb{RP}^2 \#\Bbb{RP}^2$ to me so I don't believe your homology computations either. It's an $aabbcc$, so you can decompose it as three triangles with identifications on two sides as $aa$, which is a Moebius strip/cross cap.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Yes. I must have started off with a wrong drawing altogether. :) Fixing...

Comment: This looks good now. +1 from me (I'll delete my first and last comment but leave the middle one in because it describes the space explicitly, I hope that's ok).

Comment: @BalarkaSen ;) ${}$

Comment: @BalarkaSen I had a silly mistake in the cokernel. I think you are right, and $X$ is that connected sum. The homology is indeed the correct one, and by looking at the classification of compact surfaces and their homology, your claim follows.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. I thought we had agreed that it was a connected sum. Admittedly I didn't look at the calculation in detail. But no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the cellular homology, there exists one two cell $t$, three 1-cels $a,b,c$ and 1 $0$ cells $x$.

$d_2:H_2(T_2,T_1)\rightarrow H_1(T_1,T_0)$ is defined by $d_2(t)=2a+2b+2c$,

$d_1:H_1(T_1,T_0)\rightarrow H_1(T_0,T_{-1})$ $d_1(a)=0, d_1(b)=0, d_2(c)=0$ since the vertices at the end of the 1-cell are identified.

so $H_2(T)=0$, $H_1(T)$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ by  the subgroup generated by $(2,2,2))$ and $H_0(T)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How are there *four* $0$ cells?

Comment: It seems to me there is one $0$-cell, three $1$-cells, and one $2$-cell. The maps in $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z^3\to \mathbb Z$ are, from left to right, $(2,2,2)^t$ and $0$.